# For loop variables replacement as a result of function

Tags: scala

I can't resolve multiple errors. Actually I don't understand why I can't pass variable to function as a result of the same function in for loop. Plus there's error with tuple unpacking. This is why I pack tuple(list, list) in function.

Code takes points and swaps rows of genes between 2 lists  from p until tail.

```
val points: List[Int] = List(1,3)
var chr1: List[Char] = List('x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x')
var chr2: List[Char] = List('y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y')

// def swap_genes(list1:List[Char], list2:List[Char], n: Int) doesn't work either
def swap_genes(genes: (List[Char], List[Char]), n: Int): (List[Char], List[Char]) = {
  val list1_swap = genes._1.slice(n, genes._1.size)
  val list2_swap = genes._2.slice(n, genes._2.size)
  (genes._1.patch(n, list2_swap, list1_swap.size), genes._2.patch(n, list1_swap, list2_swap.size))
}

// Problem here!
var tup:(List[Char], List[Char]) = (chr1, chr2)
for (p <- points) {
  var tup:(List[Char], List[Char]) = swap_genes(tup, p)
}


println(tup._1.mkString)
println(tup._2.mkString)
>>> xyyxx
>>> yxxyy
```

UPD. This python code works fine.

```
points = [1,3]
chr1 = ['x', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5']
chr2 = ['y', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4', 'y5']

def swap_genes(chr1, chr2, p):
    chr1_swap = chr1[p:]
    chr2_swap = chr2[p:]
    chr1[p:] = chr2_swap
    chr2[p:] = chr1_swap
    return chr1, chr2
for p in points:
    chr1, chr2 = swap_genes(chr1, chr2, p) 
print(chr1, chr2)
>>> ['x', 'y2', 'y3', 'x4', 'x5'] ['y', 'x2', 'x3', 'y4', 'y5']
```

UPD2. My solution with tail recursion. Minor changes.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
@tailrec def swap_genes(genes: (List[Char], List[Char]), points: List[Int]): (List[Char], List[Char]) = {
  points match {
    case Nil => genes
    case n::tail =>  swap_genes((genes._1.patch(n, genes._2.slice(n, genes._2.size), genes._2.size - n),
                                  genes._2.patch(n, genes._1.slice(n, genes._1.size), genes._1.size - n)), tail)
  }


}
```

Comment: It's recommended to first read basic doc/tutorial (like https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html )

Comment: @cchantep If I miss something may be You should say? Referecing into abstract info aren't smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tup:(List[Char], List[Char]) = swap_genes(tup, p)
```

This does not compile because it is trying to create a new variable `tup` but is using it before the value is set. The code that you had in one of your edits is OK because it `tup` is already defined:

```
tup = swap_genes(tup, p)
```

The better way to do this is to use the `foldLeft` operation on `points` and avoid using `var`

Answer (score 1):

Scala is a functional programming language. The way of thinking differs fundamentally from iterative programming.

A functional approach would be this one. But I don't want to say that it's the best one.

```scala
object Bla extends App {
  val pos = Set(1, 3)
  val chr1: List[Char] = List('x', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'x')
  val chr2: List[Char] = List('y', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y')

  println(Swapper.swap(chr1, chr2, pos))
}

object Swapper {

  def swap[T](a: List[T], b: List[T], positions: Set[Int]): (List[T], List[T]) = {
    assert(a.length == b.length) // delete the line if you don't need this check

    val swaps = (0 +: positions.toSeq :+ a.length).sliding(2, 1).map(x => (x.head, x.last))

    swaps.zipWithIndex.foldLeft((List.empty[T], List.empty[T])) { (o, n) =>
      val target = if(n._2 % 2 == 0) (a, b) else (b, a)
      (o._1 ++ target._1.slice(n._1._1, n._1._2), o._2 ++ target._2.slice(n._1._1, n._1._2))
    }
  }
}
```

will result in 2 Lists `('x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x')` and `('y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y')` that you can assign with `val (res1, res2) = Swapper.swap...` for instance.

Comment: Thanks for a huge response! I will analyze object Swapper, but can I cure my code somehow? generator with yield? Or basically I need knowledge of Func. Prog. to code scala?

Comment: The answer of @Tim will cure your code. You just need to change this one line with `var tup`... to `tup =` ...